Science fiction anthology meant for kids with a boarding school mind control chip and a phone that calls the past
In the early 2000s I read an anthology from my elementary school library. Two stories have stuck with me 20 years later. I'd love to find it and reread it. I distinctly remember two stories, and may be conflating the details of a third into the second, so I will list the details for that part of it separately.
First story: a girl visits her brother at boarding school. She thinks he's acting weird. He complains of headaches. She investigates and finds out every kid at this boarding school has a chip implanted that hurts them when they do anything "bad" or try and reveal the truth. To keep her quiet the people running the school convince her parents to send her there, too, and they both get stuck with the chip.
Second story: a girl finds a phone in her father's office. She finds out it lets her talk to people in the past. She talks to another girl for a while and they become good friends. The girl from the past asks how she dies, and the present girl finds out past girl dies very soon from a plane crash. The girl from the past convinces her parents to drive rather than fly and the plane lands on top of her car.
I vaguely remember something about people having to move underground because the earth surface wasn't safe.

You've included some details in the question you asked in 2009 that you haven't included here; For example, that it was an RV not a car that the plane lands on. That seems a lot more likely, tbh

If it was in an elementary school library it may well have been kids sf, maybe by someone like Nicholas Fisk. Unfortunately I've only read a very few of his books, and don't know of one that fits.
